# I have problem with char in my code,please guide me (c++)

Tags: c++

I have problem with char in my code, please guide me (c++).

I have this error: `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'op' is being used without being initialized`. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

This is my code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <iostream>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <conio.h>
#include  <math.h>

using namespace std;
enum Operations {SIN1, COS1, TAN1};

void selectenteroperation(char *szInput) {
    char *szLabels[3] = {"sin", "cos", "tan"};
    int i=0;
    while(strcmp(szInput,szLabels[i])==0)
        ++i;
    switch (i)
    {
        case SIN1: { cout<<"SIN";   break; }
        case COS1: { cout<<"COS";   break; }
        case TAN1: { cout<<"TAN";   break; }
        default:   { cout<<"Wrong"; break; }
    }
}

void main() {
    char *op;
    cout<<"op?";
    cin>>op;
    if(strcmp(op,"sin")==0) selectenteroperation("sin");
    if(strcmp(op,"cos")==0) selectenteroperation("cos");
    if(strcmp(op,"tan")==0) selectenteroperation("tan");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: i have this error : Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'op' is being used without being initialized.

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the body of your question. stackoverflow.com questions should be standalone they shouldn't rely on external links.

Comment: Uh, that compiler error sounds pretty clear to me: You're trying to use the variable `op` before you create/initialize it. Check where you declare the `op` variable, and make sure that you've initialized it before you try to use it!

Comment: @Aliexo: 7 questions now and you never **accepted** any of them (by clicking on the check mark): are you really expecting people to continue to answer when you don't seem to care about thanking those who use their time to help you ?

Comment: Moved extra info from comment to question to make it more of a real question. Hopefully will be re-opened but you can never tell.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `char *op` creates just a character pointer, *not* the backing storage to hold the string.

Since this is C++, you should be using `std::string`. Old style C strings have their uses but easy-to-use strings is not one of them.

Embrace C++, there are more than enough C programmers trying to pass themselves off as C++ gurus as it is :-)

Since this looks like homework, I won't give you back your fully fixed program but I *will* give you one that can be used as a basis for testing and, more importantly, understanding:

```
pax$ cat qq.cpp ; g++ -o qq qq.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Enter something: ";
    std::cin >> s;  // or getline (std::cin, s).
    std::cout << "You entered [" << s << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

pax$ ./qq
Enter something: hello
You entered [hello]
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to use C strings, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    char s[256];
    std::cout << "Enter something: ";
    std::cin.getline (s, sizeof (s));
    std::cout << "You entered [" << s << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

may be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out the standard template library [string class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead of using a C-string (char*) for your op variable.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you probably want to change the line:

```
while(strcmp(szInput,szLabels[i])==0)
```

to

```
while(strcmp(szInput,szLabels[i])!=0)
```

edit:But you should also have a test here to make sure i doesn't exceed 2.

And of course you also need to allocate memory for *op, like this:

```
char *op = new char[256] ;
```

(I just chose 256 arbitrarily here).

UPDATE: To test that i is less than 3:

```
while(i<3 && strcmp(szInput,szLabels[i])!=0)
```

Comment: TNX,this is work,but i have one problem,my defualt case in switch not work :(

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that i is less than 3 in your test. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading into a uninitalized `char*` pointer. A quick (if somewhat dangerous fix) would be to write:

```
 char op[100];
```

instead of

```
  char* op;
```

but using std::strings is much safer as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't have a char -- you have a pointer to a char.  The pointer is uninitialised.

```
char *op;
cout<<"op?";
cin>>op;
```

Do something like

```
char *op = new char[100];
```

Or use std::string instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *op;
cout>op;
```

The above code is wrong. Trying to write to some memory that has not been initialized !!

Try using a char array or a string instead of a raw char pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems:

- `strcmp` returns `0` when the strings are EQUAL, not when they're different
- you should think a way to stop searching once you get to the end of `szLabels`
- string literals cannot be altered and so it's better to use `const char *` in that case
- `main` should not declared that way (it's not a `void` function)
- `cin >> op` is not going to allocate the needed memory for your input
- C++ has a `std::string` class that can solve many of the above issues and seems to be just the right thing to use here

I hope you're not going to feel offended, but to me looks like you're using C++ as the first language to learning about programming. I personally think this is a recipe for a disaster.

If for some strange reason you really must use this difficult path then my suggestion is to start from a [good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and following examples first.

C++ isn't a good language for just "try and see". IMO typing in code and trying to compile is bad in general, but is a true suicide with a language powerful but complex and asymmetric as it is C++ especially if you consider that when you make a mistake often C++ will just [laugh at you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) instead of clearing telling you where is the mistake.